# Set picture to appear in Timeline when page is 'Liked'?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-timeline

Whenever a user Likes/Comments on a page of my website, and it subsequently appears in their timeline as a post, the image/icon that appears with the post is one of the social icons from said page (i,e the StumbleUpon/Tweet icon) and not the preview image.

Is there a way to set the preview image that appears with the timeline post when a user Likes/Comments on a page?

Here's an example of what I am referring to (in this case with a StumbleUpon icon from the page):

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you specified  tag in head of your page.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="tag value"/>
```

where "og:image" is the URL to an image that represents the entity. Images must be at least 50 pixels by 50 pixels. Square images work best, but you are allowed to use images up to three times as wide as they are tall.

This image is pulled from the website on Facebook page when a user likes or comments on your website where like button is placed

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `og:image` meta tag on page. Image specified that way will appear in published post (no matter where post is displayed timeline or feed)